# WCF client receives 407 authentication error on Win7

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WinForms app that contains a WCF client using .NET 3.5.  I have two machines, 1 WinXp, the other Win7.  Both have the same settings in IE in regards to the proxy settings.  In my app.config file i have set:

```
 <system.net>
     <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
         <proxy proxyaddress = "http://proxyserver:80" bypassonlocal = "true"/>
     </defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```

This works fine on the WinXp machine, but on the Win7 machine I still get the `407 Authentication Required` error.  I feel like ive tried every combination of proxy settings at the system.net level, and in the WCF client Bindings section with no luck.  What could possible be causing this difference?

Answer (score 0):

On the binding element you can specify to use the default proxy. Set it to false to see if this helps? Probably you can remove the defaultProxy from the system.net section.

```
<bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding useDefaultWebProxy="false">
     </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings/>
```

[Msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

Building the application for targetframework 4.0 ( instead of 3.0 ) solved the problem.

The application runs now on xp ( with dot.net 4.0 installed ) as well as on win 7.

It's a pity! I would expect applications build for a inverior target version will always run on systems with a higher version.